# _renderIndex if not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code

```
module.exports = {
    _renderIndex: async (req, res) => {
       console.dir("test");
    },
    index: async (req, res) => {
          this._renderIndex(req, res, {});
     }
 };
```

Unfortunately, when I run the function index, I get the error this._renderIndex is not a function. Can someone please tell me why?

Comment: `this` is not a reference to `module.exports`. Write `module.exports._renderIndex` instead.

Comment: I'd define the functions using `function` then do `module.exports = { _renderIndex, index };`

Answer (score 0):

The object you are trying to reference by `this` doesn't exist yet

Try just defining it first and not using `this`

```
const _renderIndex = async (req, res) => {
  console.dir("test");
}

module.exports = {
    _renderIndex,
    index: async (req, res) => {
      _renderIndex(req, res, {});
    }
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

render.js

```js
const _renderIndex = async (req, res) => {
  console.dir("test");
}
const index=(){}
module.exports ={renderIndex:_renderIndex,index:index};
```

in another file

```js
 import {renderIndex,index} from 'render.js'
```